# Delete rows with duplicate values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with codes, registered in different times (columns). Like this way:

```py
   time1 time2 time3  time4
0  A09.9 B25   A02.2  NaN
1  B21   J2    Z23.1  J2
2  C21.2 C03   NaN    NaN
```

I need to remove the rows with duplicate values in any column, so in this case it would be the second row.

```py
   time1 time2 time3  time4
0  A09.9 B25   A02.2  NaN
1  C21.2 C03   NaN    NaN
```

I haven't found any efficient way, just going from row to row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We using `nuinque` with `notnull` value count

```
df[df.nunique(1)==df.notnull().sum(1)]
Out[154]: 
   time1 time2  time3 time4
0  A09.9   B25  A02.2   NaN
2  C21.2   C03    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: That's nice! I was thinking about a version with `melt` combined with `groupby`, but I guess that would not have come close to the performance of this solution.